# Can't send a variable to javascript from java

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I'm fetching a url and trying to send it's text content to a javascript function inside a webview.

I do this from the java code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://volteck.net");
// Get the response
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);

response_str = response_str.replaceAll("\n", "\\");
// this is because js don't support multi-line strings

myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myfunction('" + response_str + "')");
System.out.println("javascript:myfunction('" + response_str + "')");
```

This is code that is inside the webview:

```
function myfunction(val){
    document.body.innerHTML = val.length;
    }
```

So far I'm only trying to get the text length. But when I use the url of previous code, nothing happens. and I get this from the log:

08-19 23:55:03.141: I/dalvikvm-heap(1846): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.551MB for 262160-byte allocation
08-19 23:55:03.351: D/dalvikvm(1846): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 209ms

But the weird thing is that if I attempt to fetch volteck.net/ip, that only contains an IP number, it works just fine!

Thanks a lot from a Java newbie.

Comment: Are you trying to call js by printing it out with system.out?

Comment: I accidentally deleted the line that calls the js function inside the webview when posting the question, now edited, sorry about that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();   
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String script = "function myfunction(val){
document.body.innerHTML = val.length;
}";   
engine.eval(script);   
Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
inv.invokeFunction("myfunction", response_str );
```